# How can I vertically align a Parent and its child in a hortizontally aligned ul?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Here is an image:
[What I am trying to align vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJjd5.png)

I am trying to align these items with the icon on top of the text
Here is my code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar {
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.navbar ul li .leftNav {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.navbar ul li .middleNav {
    display: inline;
    float: center;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li .rightNav {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

and my html:

```
extends layout

block content
  .navbar
    ul 
      li 
        a(class="leftNav" href="#") Movies
          i(class="fas fa-film icon")
      li 
        a(class="leftNav" href="#") Series
          i(class="fas fa-film icon")
      li
        h1(class="middleNav")= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

There is probably a simple solution I am missing here but any help is appreciated since I have been looking around for 30 minutes and still haven't found any solution to this on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by updating the following HTML

```
.navbar
  img(src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJjd5.png', alt='', style='display: block;')
  ul(style='display: block;')
    li
      a.leftNav(href='#')
        | Movies
        i.fas.fa-film.icon
    li
      a.leftNav(href='#')
        | Series
        i.fas.fa-film.icon
    li
      h1.middleNav
p Welcome to
```

and update your CSS:

```
.navbar {
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
i {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

but it is usually hacky to get it perfect, I usually use flexbox for alignment

```
.navbar ul li .leftNav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `display:flex` and `align-items: center` to the `li` element to get the desired result. You can check out the code below

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
li a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" class="leftNav">
      <span>Movies</span>
      <i class="fas fa-film icon"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" class="leftNav">
      <span>Series</span>
      <i class="fas fa-film icon"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```